# Plotting distances of consecutive samples as a function of their time lag in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset, distance

My data set has samples as rows and variables as cols (X1-X3).
Each sample is a combination of one of eight sites (a-h) at 10 times (1-10).

```
df = data.frame(site = c(rep ("a", 10), rep("b",10),rep("c",10),
                         rep("d",10),rep("e",10), rep("f",10), 
                         rep("g",10),rep("h", 10)),
                  time = rep(1:10,8),
                matrix(rnorm(80*3), nrow=80))
```

I calculated a Euclidean distance matrix for my samples using the `dist` function, so that the distance between each pair of samples is calculated and the diagonal is the distance of each sample to itself (=0).

```
mx = as.matrix (df)
rownames (mx) = paste(df$site, df$time)
mx = subset (mx, select = -c(site, time))
dist.mx = as.matrix (dist(mx, method = "euclidean"))
```

For each site, I would like to plot the distances between consequent samples as a function of their lag times. Such as in the first lag there are 9 distance values (i.e. the distance of years 1-2, 2-3, 3-4...), in lag 2 there will be 8 distances (i.e. between years 1-3, 2-4, 3-5, 4-6...), in lag 3 - 7 distances (i.e. 1-4, 2-5, 3-6, 4-7... Overall 45 data points for each site. See example below (please only refer to the data in maroon).

[image] (Lamothe et al., 2019)

Comment: Could you share an example dataset so that we can study it? If would be easier to help you if you do that.

Comment: Thank you. I've added dummy data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Convert to longer data frame
dist.mx %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("col1") %>%
  pivot_longer(-col1, names_to = "col2", values_to = "dist") %>%

  # extract site and time from each sample
  separate(col1, c("site1", "time1"), convert = T) %>%
  separate(col2, c("site2", "time2"), convert = T) %>%

  # compare lags within sites
  filter(site1 == site2, time1 < time2) %>%
  mutate(lag = time2 - time1) %>%

  ggplot(aes(lag, dist)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, minor_breaks = NULL) +
  facet_wrap(~site1)
```

[image]